# Parse Through Nested Array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, nested-loops

How to iterate through PHP array 
This is the output of var_export

```
   array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'place' => 'GreenPepper',
        'Distance' => '0.487',
        'Lat' => '8.52699',
        'Lng' => '76.92419100000006',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'place' => 'BAKE \'N\' COOL',
        'Distance' => '0.513',
        'Lat' => '8.527908',
        'Lng' => '76.92643599999997',
      ),
    )
```

### PHP

```
for ($row = 0; $row < sizeof($obj); $row++) {

 echo $value[$row][place];


}
```

It the suppossed output was `GreenPepper0.487` but instead it was getting this

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant place - assumed 'place' in C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\SortJson.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant Distance - assumed 'Distance' in C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\SortJson.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
GreenPepper0.487<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant place - assumed 'place' in C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\SortJson.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Use of undefined constant Distance - assumed 'Distance' in C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246592</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\SortJson.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\SortJson.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

### EDIT

The cause was a typo 
 echo `$value[$row]['place'];` instead of this echo `$value[$row][place];` solved the issue

Comment: With a [`foreach ($ARRAY as $ROW)`](http://php.net/foreach)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` to go through your php array

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row['place'].' '.$row['Distance'].' '.$row['Lat'].' '.$row['Lng'];
}
```

Comment: Found Out the error myself But thanks for effort +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this,

```
<?php

$myArray = array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'place' => 'GreenPepper',
        'Distance' => '0.487',
        'Lat' => '8.52699',
        'Lng' => '76.92419100000006',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'place' => 'BAKE \'N\' COOL',
        'Distance' => '0.513',
        'Lat' => '8.527908',
        'Lng' => '76.92643599999997',
      ),
    );

foreach($myArray as $value){
    echo $value['place'] . " ";
    echo $value['Distance'] . " ";
    echo $value['Lat'] . " ";
    echo $value['Lng'] . " ";
}

?>
```

Comment: Found Out the error myself But thanks for effort +1